# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer JAVA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, dao

i got an error after submit my set to database like this

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

And, i dont have no idea about to parse this List to integer

```
carFamilySelectList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        List<CarFamily> carFamilyList = carFamilyServiceImpl.selectCarFamilyIdList();
        carFamilySelectList.add(new SelectItem("", "Select one"));
        for(CarFamily  as : carFamilyList) {
            carFamilySelectList.add(new SelectItem(as.getCarFamilyId(), as.getCarFamilyName()));
        }
```

Please help!

Comment: Googling "Java how to parse string to int" gets lots of hits. One way to do this is ``Integer.parseInt(String)``

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without what line of code in the database(?) is throwing the exception but my guess is that the cause is that first list entry that's causing the problem:

`carFamilySelectList.add(new SelectItem("", "Select one"));`

I'm assuming that `CarFamily.getCarFamilyId()` returns an int, and that the return value of `SelectItem.getValue()` is being cast to an Integer somewhere? That first list entry is a `SelectItem` with an empty string as its value. Try using 0 (or -1 or whatever) instead:

`carFamilySelectList.add(new SelectItem(0, "Select one"));`

But in the future, include more relevant information in your question (the line where the exception is thrown and at least the signatures for the methods in your custom class that are relevant to your question... like `getCarFamilyId()` in this case).